# Hough Transform Equivalent in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have attached a Code of *Hough Transform* in MATLAB below:

```
%Hough Transform to find lines

%Load an Image and Convert to Grayscale to apply canny Filter
im = imread('lines.jpg');
im_gray = rgb2gray(im);
im_edge = edge(im_gray, 'canny');

figure, imshow(im), title('Original Image');
figure, imshow(im_gray), title('Grayscale Image');
figure, imshow(im_edge), title('Canny Filter Edge');

%Apply Hough Transform to Find the Candidate Lines
[accum theta rho] = hough(im_edge);
figure, imagesc(accum, 'xData', theta, 'ydata', rho), title('Hough Accumulator');

peaks = houghpeaks(accum, 100, 'Threshold', ceil(0.6 * max(accum(:))),'NHoodSize', [5,5]);
size(peaks);

%Finding the line segments in the image
line_segs = houghlines(edges, theta, rows, peaks, 'FillGap', 50,'MinLength', 100);

%Plotting
figure, imshow(im), title('Line Segments');
hold on;
for k=1:length(line_segs)
  endpoints = [line_segs(k).point1; line_segs(k).point2];
  plot(endpoints(:,1), endpoints(:,2), 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color','green');
end
hold off;
```

When I'm trying to implement the same in OCTAVE by changing the *'hough into houghtf'*, *'houghlines to hough_line'* and *'houghpeaks into immaximas'* in the following way:

```
%Hough Transform to find lines
pkg load image;

%Load an Image and Convert to Grayscale to apply canny Filter
im = imread('lines.jpg');
im_gray = rgb2gray(im);
im_edge = edge(im_gray, 'canny');

figure, imshow(im), title('Original Image');
figure, imshow(im_gray), title('Grayscale Image');
figure, imshow(im_edge), title('Canny Filter Edge');

%Apply Hough Transform to Find the Candidate Lines
[accum theta rho] = houghtf(im_edge); %In Octave and 'hough' in MATLAB
figure, imagesc(accum, 'xData', theta, 'ydata', rho), title('Hough Accumulator');

peaks = immaximas(accum, 100, 'Threshold', ceil(0.6 * max(accum(:))),'NHoodSize', [5,5]);
size(peaks);

%Finding the line segments in the image
line_segs = hough_line(edges, theta, rows, peaks, 'FillGap', 50, 'MinLength', 100);

%Plotting
figure, imshow(im), title('Line Segments');
hold on;
for k=1:length(line_segs)
 endpoints = [line_segs(k).point1; line_segs(k).point2];
 plot(endpoints(:,1), endpoints(:,2), 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'green');
end
hold off;
```

I get the following error while executing it:

```
error: element number 3 undefined in return list
error: called from
HoughTransformLines at line 14 column 18
```

I am getting the error stating *'rho'* is undefined.
I am completely new to MATLAB and Octave. Can anyone please help me implement the Hough-Transform in Octave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why Octave tells you that `rho` is undefined is because Matlab's [hough](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html) function and Octave's [houghtf](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/houghtf.html) function are not exact equivalents.

Here's the description of the output arguments returned by **hough** from the corresponding Mathwork's webpage:

> The function returns rho, the distance from the origin to the line
>   along a vector perpendicular to the line, and theta, the angle in
>   degrees between the x-axis and this vector. The function also returns
>   the Standard Hough Transform, H, which is a parameter space matrix
>   whose rows and columns correspond to rho and theta values
>   respectively.

Octave's **houghtf**, on the other hand, only returns matrix H:

> The result H is an N by M matrix containing the Hough transform. Here,
>   N is the number different values of r that has been attempted. This is
>   computed as 2*diag_length - 1, where diag_length is the length of the
>   diagonal of the input image. M is the number of different values of
>   theta. These can be set through the third input argument arg. This
>   must be a vector of real numbers, and is by default pi*(-90:90)/180.

Now, in your script, the only place where you call `rho` is on line 15, when trying to display the Hough accumulator.
I suggest you instead plot the accumulator this way:

```
figure, imagesc(H),xlabel('xData'),ylabel('ydata'),title('Hough accumulator')
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: It works the way you suggested to plot the accumulator.

But i had to remove 'rho' from Line 15:
`[accum theta] = houghtf(im_edge);`

But still getting this error:
`error: immaximas: third input argument must be a scalar or an empty matrix
error: called from
    immaximas at line 76 column 5
    HoughTransformLines at line 18 column 7`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following updates for the original code:

```
%Hough Transform to find lines
pkg load image;

%Load an Image and Convert to Grayscale to apply canny Filter
im = imread('lines.jpg');
im_gray = rgb2gray(im);
im_edge = edge(im_gray, 'canny');

figure 1, imshow(im),      title('Original Image');
figure 2, imshow(im_gray), title('Grayscale Image');
figure 3, imshow(im_edge), title('Canny Filter Edge');

%Apply Hough Transform to Find the Candidate Lines
accum       = houghtf(im_edge);
theta       = -90:90;
diag_length = (size(accum)(1) - 1) / 2;
rho         = -diag_length:diag_length;
figure 4, imagesc(theta, rho, accum), title('Hough Accumulator');

peaks = houghpeaks(accum, 100, 'Threshold', ceil(0.6 * max(accum(:))), 'NHoodSize', [5,5]);

%Finding the line segments in the image
line_segs = houghlines(im_edge, theta, rho, peaks, 'FillGap', 50, 'MinLength', 100);

%Plotting
figure 5, imshow(im), title('Line Segments');
hold on;
for k=1:length(line_segs)
    endpoints = [line_segs(k).point1; line_segs(k).point2];
    plot(endpoints(:,1), endpoints(:,2), 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'green');
end
hold off;
```

Let's walk through all updates and review them:

```
%Hough Transform to find lines
pkg load image;

%Load an Image and Convert to Grayscale to apply canny Filter
im = imread('lines.jpg');
im_gray = rgb2gray(im);
im_edge = edge(im_gray, 'canny');

figure 1, imshow(im),      title('Original Image');
figure 2, imshow(im_gray), title('Grayscale Image');
figure 3, imshow(im_edge), title('Canny Filter Edge');
```

There are only very minor changes - the indices for the figures were added to divide them into consistent separate windows (see [Multiple Plot Windows](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Multiple-Plot-Windows.html)).

After that we are applying Hough transform and restoring "lost" `theta` and `rho` values in the Octave:

```
%Apply Hough Transform to Find the Candidate Lines
accum       = houghtf(im_edge);
theta       = -90:90;
diag_length = (size(accum)(1) - 1) / 2;
rho         = -diag_length:diag_length;
figure 4, imagesc(theta, rho, accum), title('Hough Accumulator');
```

According to the [`houghtf`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/houghtf.html) function's docs, it returns only an accumulator with rows corresponding to indices of rho values, and columns - to indices of theta values. How can we restore the original rho and theta values? Well, the number of rho values (rows in the `accum` matrix variable) goes up to `2*diag_length - 1`, where `diag_length` is the length of the diagonal of the input image. Knowing this, we should restore the diagonal length (it is a reversed action): `diag_length = (size(accum)(1) - 1) / 2`. Then we can restore `rho` values, which go from minus diagonal to diagonal: `rho = -diag_length:diag_length`. With thetas everything is easier - they are in the range of `pi*(-90:90)/180`, but we will use degrees instead: `theta = -90:90`. I've added the index for `figure` as did before and changed the call to `imagesc` according to its [docs](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/imagesc.html) - it should be called as `imagesc (x, y, img)`.

After that we use [`houghpeaks`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/houghpeaks.html) function to get the peaks:

```
peaks = houghpeaks(accum, 100, 'Threshold', ceil(0.6 * max(accum(:))), 'NHoodSize', [5,5]);
```

And we use [`houghlines`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/houghlines.html) to get the result line segments (guess there were some errata with variables' names):

```
line_segs = houghlines(im_edge, theta, rho, peaks, 'FillGap', 50, 'MinLength', 100);
```

And finally there goes plotting code - it wasn't changed at all, because it worked correctly.

Answer (score -1):

```
[H] = houghtf(edges);
```

You have to pass the argument in this manner since the octave returns only a matrix of values. you can't assign three different variables to a matrix.
So, assign a single variable to that and you will get the result.